# How to deal with relations in Vuex/Pinia stores and keep them in sync?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm using Vue3 with the composition API. For this example, I will use Pinia but this applies to Vuex as well.

Imagine you have to take care of entity A holding entities of type entity B. For this example I will use a single todo holding multiple labels.

The sample store for the labels

```
export type Label = {
  title: string; // "unique"
};

export const useLabelsStore = defineStore("labels", () => {
  const labels = ref<Label[]>([]);

  function addLabel(title: string): void {
    if (!labels.value.some((label) => label.title === title)) {
      labels.value.push({ title });
    }
  }

  function deleteLabel(title: string): void {
    labels.value = labels.value.filter((label) => label.title !== title);
  }

  return { labels, addLabel, deleteLabel };
});
```

and for the todos

```
export type Todo = {
  title: string; // "unique"
  labels: Label[];
};

export const useTodosStore = defineStore("todos", () => {
  const todos = ref<Todo[]>([{ title: "foo", labels: [] }]);

  function applyLabelToTodo(todoTitle: string, label: Label) {
    const todo = todos.value.find((todo) => todo.title === todoTitle);

    if (
      todo &&
      !todo.labels.some((todoLabel) => todoLabel.title === label.title)
    ) {
      todo.labels.push(label);
    }
  }

  return { todos, applyLabelToTodo };
});
```

You can create todos, labels and apply labels to todos. But after applying a label to a todo and deleting it afterwards the todo still holds it, the code has no sync mechanism yet, so the todos store is no "invalid" / "outdated".

**This shows the App.vue file for testing purposes**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>Labels: {{ labelsStore.labels }}</div>

    <br />

    <div v-for="todo in todosStore.todos" :key="todo.title">
      <div>Todo: {{ todo.title }}</div>
      <div>Applied labels: {{ todo.labels }}</div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <button @click="addLabel">Add new label</button>

    <br />
    <br />

    <select v-model="selectedLabelTitle">
      <option
        v-for="label in labelsStore.labels"
        :value="label.title"
        :key="label.title"
      >
        {{ label.title }}
      </option>
    </select>

    <button @click="labelsStore.deleteLabel(selectedLabelTitle)">
      Delete label "{{ selectedLabelTitle }}"
    </button>
    <button @click="applyLabelToTodo">
      Apply label "{{ selectedLabelTitle }}" to todo "{{
        todosStore.todos[0].title
      }}"
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";

import { useTodosStore } from "./todosStore";
import { useLabelsStore } from "./labelsStore";

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const todosStore = useTodosStore();
    const labelsStore = useLabelsStore();

    const selectedLabelTitle = ref<string>();

    function addLabel(): void {
      labelsStore.addLabel(`Label ${labelsStore.labels.length + 1}`);
    }

    function applyLabelToTodo(): void {
      const label = labelsStore.labels.find(
        (label) => label.title === selectedLabelTitle.value
      );

      if (label) {
        todosStore.applyLabelToTodo(todosStore.todos[0].title, label);
      }
    }

    return {
      todosStore,
      labelsStore,
      addLabel,
      selectedLabelTitle,
      applyLabelToTodo,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

- The todos store already has a todo
- Click on "Add new label"
- Select it in the select box
- Apply that label to the todo
- Delete that label

You will see that this todo still holds the deleted label.

What is the common way to synchronize the stores? My current solution based on [subscribing to actions](https://pinia.esm.dev/core-concepts/actions.html#subscribing-to-actions) is extending the todos store

```
export const useTodosStore = defineStore("todos", () => {
  // ...

  const labelsStore = useLabelsStore();

  labelsStore.$onAction((context) => {
    if (context.name === "deleteLabel") {
      context.after(() => {
        todos.value = todos.value.map((todo) => {
          todo.labels = todo.labels.filter(
            (label) => label.title !== context.args[0]
          );

          return todo;
        });
      });
    }
  });

  // ...
});
```

Do I have to listen for all the actions or are there any better ways?

Comment: By using `getters`? It's not really different if these are different stores, Vue computeds just work

Comment: Hey, would you mind describing how to solve it with getters? I updated my question, I hope this is easier to understand now

Comment: Don't use factory function for `defineStore` and Vue reactivity API (`ref`, etc). I guess I saw this from another user too and not sure where this idea comes from. Pinia allows this but it's advanced feature that wasn't advertised much. Just follow the example from Pinia docs - `state`, `getters`, etc properties in `defineStore`. No function.

Comment: I took it from here https://pinia.esm.dev/introduction.html#basic-example, search for the term `You can even use a function (similar to a component setup()) to define a Store for more advanced use cases`. But how would you solve this using the options API?

Comment: "even". A function is an edge case that is rarely ever needed. It's not a component, it doesn't need options API. It has it's own API similar to Vuex. Every other example on that page uses it, that's how it's usually used.

Answer (score 1):

Factory function that defines a store and allows to define it with Vue reactive API directly is advanced feature that is generally not needed. A store is commonly defined with an object that is similar to Vuex API.

Values that are supposed to derive from other values are supposed to go to getters, very similarly to Vue computed values (`computed` is a part of Vue reactive API and used by Pinia internally).

There are many ways to do this, for instance, todo labels can be filtered against up-to-date labels from another store

```
const todoStore = defineStore({
  state: () => ({ _todos: [] })
  getters: {
    todos() {
      const labelStore = useLabelStore();

      return this._todos
      .map((todo) => ({
        ...todo,
        labels: todo.labels.filter(label => labelStore.labels.includes(label))
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think this approach is less efficient. When creating many labels, applying them to todos and deleting them, you would never clean up. They would be filtered but they slow down the filter loop over time ...

Comment: FWIW, this is how Redux works, and it doesn't even have cache tier that computed value provides. In case performance is an issue, this needs to be proved with tests, not deduced. It *can* be more efficient to watch on another store instead, but not necessarily.